# Why does the compiler complain about this not being a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, constexpr

I am trying to learn a bit more on how to use C++ constant expressions in practice and created the following Matrix class template for illustration purposes:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, int numrows, int numcols>
class Matrix{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    constexpr Matrix() : {}
   ~Matrix(){}

    constexpr Matrix(const std::array<T, numrows*numcols>& a) :
        values_(a){}

    constexpr Matrix(const Matrix& other) :
        values_(other.values_){

    }

    constexpr const T& operator()(int row, int col) const {
        return values_[row*numcols+col];
    }

    T& operator()(int row, int col){
        return values_[row*numcols+col];
    }

    constexpr int rows() const {
        return numrows;
    }

    constexpr int columns() const {
        return numcols;
    }


private:
    std::array<T, numrows*numcols> values_{};
};
```

The idea is to have a simple Matrix class, which I can use for small matrices to evaluate Matrix expressions at compile time (note that I have not yet implemented the usual Matrix operators for addition and multiplication).

When I try to initialize a Matrix instance as follows:

```
constexpr std::array<double, 4> a = {1,1,1,1};
constexpr Matrix<double, 2, 2> m(a);
```

I am getting the following error from the compiler (MS Visual C++ 14):

```
error: C2127: 'm': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression
```

Note sure what I am doing wrong...any help to make this work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `std::array` doesn't have a constexpr copy constructor?

Comment: Remove the destructor's definition

Comment: As a sidenote, there is no need to store `numrows_` and `numcols_` as member variables. Since you have the values as template parameters already, just return those.

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki yes that did the trick. Thanks! If you post this as an answer I will accept it. But I don't understand why defining a destructor triggers the error?

Comment: @nasser-sh as suggested I cleaned up the code by removing unnecessary member variables for row and column size

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[[basic.types]/p10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#10) states that:

> A type is a *literal type* if it is:
>
> - possibly cv-qualified `void`; or
> - a scalar type; or
> - a reference type; or
> - an array of literal type; or
> - a possibly cv-qualified class type (Clause [[class]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class)) that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - it is either a closure type ([[expr.prim.lambda]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda)), an aggregate type ([[dcl.init.aggr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr)), or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template (possibly inherited ([[namespace.udecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl)) from a base class) that is not a copy or move constructor,
>   - if it is a union, at least one of its non-static data members is of non-volatile literal type, and
>   - if it is not a union, all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

where [[class.dtor]/p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#5) says that:

> A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> <sup>(5.4)</sup> — the destructor is not `virtual`,
>
> <sup>(5.5)</sup> — all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors, and
>
> <sup>(5.6)</sup> — for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such
>   class has a trivial destructor.
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is *non-trivial*.

In other words, to declare a `constexpr` instance of `Matrix`, it must be a literal type, and to be a literal type, its destructor must be either `default`ed, or removed altogether, so:

```
~Matrix() = default;
```

or:

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the clarifications!

Comment: I like the _or_. :-)