# How to initialise a constexpr matrix of type Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>?

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-specialization, template-argument-deduction

I was not really able to summarize the problem in the question. I already made a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012758/how-to-define-a-static-constexpr-matrix-in-c14).There I asked help for defining `static constexpr` matrices. The solution was to add another argument to the list of the template matrix, basically `Matrix<T,Rows,Cols,std::make_index_sequence<Rows*Cols>>`.

I accepted the answer, but later I noticed that with this version, my older code was not able to support the call of functions which have as argument a `Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>`, for example as:

```
foo(Matrix<T,Rows,Cols> & foo){...}
```

since the absence of the fourth implicit parameter was giving me a compile error, i.e. `candidate template ignored: could not match '__make_integer_seq' against 'integer_sequence'`.

1. Can someone, please, explain to me why and what should I do to fix
   this? I guess it is fixable but I was not able to figure it out.

Then I found out that I can define the class in a different manner, maintaining the classic structure `Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>`, but still being able to define `static constexpr` matrices (I just added what is necessary here):

```
template<typename T, Integer Rows_, Integer Cols_>
class Matrix {
public:

    static constexpr Integer Rows=Rows_;
    static constexpr Integer Cols=Cols_;
    using type= Matrix<T,Rows,Cols>;
    using subtype=T;

    ~Matrix()=default; 

    Matrix() {}

    template<typename...Inputs>
          constexpr Matrix (const Inputs&...vals)
          : values{{ {static_cast<T>(vals)}...}}
          {static_assert(sizeof...(Inputs)==Rows*Cols, "...");}


private:

   std::array<T, Rows * Cols> values;
};
```

So with the `static_cast()` in the constructor I can define static matrices without changing the template of the Matrix class. I can do something as

```
 static constexpr Matrix< double, 2, 2> A{1.,2.,3.,4.};
```

but I can also maintain the call to functions like `foo(Matrix<T,Rows,Cols> & foo){...}`. So I was ok with this solution. But then I tried to create a matrix of matrices and I found out that this class version fails in the constructor of this kind:

```
Matrix< Matrix<double,1,1>, 2, 2> A{{0.1},{0.1},{0.1},{0.1}};
```

even though it succeeds if I first initialize the elements and then I pass them as argument:

```
    static constexpr Matrix< double, 1,1> a{{0.1}};
    static constexpr Matrix< Matrix<double,1,1>, 2, 2> A{a,a,a,a};
```

However, I would like to avoid this, if possible.

As a more clarifying example I will give this:

```
Matrix< Matrix<Real,1,1>, 2, 2> A{a,a,a,{0.1}};
```

which gives the following compile error:

````
candidate template ignored: substitution failure : deduced incomplete pack <Matrix<double, 1, 1>, Matrix<double, 1, 1>, Matrix<double, 1, 1>,
      (no value)> for template parameter 'Inputs'``` (so ```{0.1}``` is no value).
````

If instead of `{0.1}` I write the constructor `Matrix<double,1,1>{0.1}`, then it works, but it is horrible to look at.

---

2. Why cannot I simply construct the elements of the matrix by means of
   the series of `{0.1}`? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can someone, please, explain to me why and what should I do to fix this? I guess it is fixable but I was not able to figure it out.

I can't explain.

I can confirm that clang++ gives the error but g++ compile without problem. I suspect a clang++ bug (or a not standard compliance) but I'm not an expert. I intend to simplify the problem and propose it as a separate question.

How to fix? You can add a level of inheritance.

You can create a `Matrix_base` class that make the trick of `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence`

```
template <typename, typename>
class Matrix_base;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
class Matrix_base<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { 
   // values_ and constructors
 };
```

and inherit it from a `Matrix` class whit only three template parameter

```
template <typename T, std::size_t NR, std::size_t NC>
class Matrix : public Matrix_base<T, std::make_index_sequence<NR*NC>>
 {
   public:
      using value_type = T;

      using MB = Matrix_base<T, std::make_index_sequence<NR*NC>>;

      using MB::MB;
      using MB::values_;

      // other methods
 };
```

A complete example follows

> Why cannot I simply construct the elements of the matrix by means of the series of {0.1}? Is there any workaround for this?

The problem is the type deduction.

If you have a constructor

```
template<typename...Inputs>
      constexpr Matrix (const Inputs&...vals)
      : values{{ {static_cast<T>(vals)}...}}
      {static_assert(sizeof...(Inputs)==Rows*Cols, "...");}
```

that receive a variadic sequence of `Input...` argument, where the compiler **must** **deduce** the `Inputs...` types from the `vals...` values, you can't pass something as `{0.1}` (or maybe `{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}`) as a value hoping that the compiler can deduce a type from it.

Different if you have the original constructor

```
  constexpr Matrix (getType<value_type, Is> ... vals)
     : values_{{vals...}}
   {}
```

where `getType<value_type, Is>` become `value_type`. You have a constructor that expect a sequence of `sizeof...(Is)` elements of a known type: `value_type`. So no type has to be deduced: when the `Matrix` constructor expects four element of type `Matrix<double, 1u, 1u>`, if you pass four argument `{0.1}` (or also four `0.1`) the compiler know that `{0.1}` must be used to initialize a `Matrix<double, 1u, 1u>`.

---

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using getType = T;

template <typename, typename>
class Matrix_base;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
class Matrix_base<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   protected:
      std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> values_{};

   public:
      constexpr Matrix_base (getType<T, Is> ... vals)
         : values_{{vals...}}
       {}

      constexpr Matrix_base (std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> const & a)
         : values_{a}
       {}

      constexpr Matrix_base (std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> && a)
         : values_{std::move(a)}
       {}

      constexpr Matrix_base () = default;

      ~Matrix_base() = default;

      constexpr Matrix_base (Matrix_base const &) = default;
      constexpr Matrix_base (Matrix_base &&) = default;

      constexpr Matrix_base & operator= (Matrix_base const &) = default;
      constexpr Matrix_base & operator= (Matrix_base &&) = default;
 };

template <typename T, std::size_t NR, std::size_t NC>
class Matrix : public Matrix_base<T, std::make_index_sequence<NR*NC>>
 {
   public:
      using value_type = T;

      using MB = Matrix_base<T, std::make_index_sequence<NR*NC>>;

      using MB::MB;
      using MB::values_;

      constexpr T const & operator() (std::size_t r, std::size_t c) const
       { return values_[r*NC+c]; }

      T & operator() (std::size_t r, std::size_t c)
       { return values_[r*NC+c]; }

      constexpr std::size_t rows () const
       { return NR; }

      constexpr std::size_t columns () const
       { return NC; }
 };

template <typename T, std::size_t Dim1, std::size_t Dim2>
void foo (Matrix<T, Dim1, Dim2> const &)
 { }

int main()
 {
   static constexpr Matrix<double,2,2> staticmat{0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4};

   Matrix<Matrix<double,1,1>, 2, 2> a{{0.1}, {0.1}, {0.1}, {0.1}};
   Matrix<Matrix<double,1,1>, 2, 2> b{0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};

   foo(staticmat);
   foo(a);
   foo(b);
 }
```

Comment: Ok, so I was lucky that, with the static cast, the compiler has been able to make the deduction type at least for the simpler cases. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Garo - En passant, I've added a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133186/g-and-clang-different-behaviour-when-stdmake-index-sequence-and-stdin) regarding the compilation error (clang++ only); no answer at the moment but seems to me that a common suspect is that is a clang++ bug/non conformance.