# g++ and clang++ different behaviour when `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` are used for a template parameter default type

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-specialization, template-argument-deduction

Another "who's right between g++ and clang++?" question for C++ standard gurus.

Given the following code

```
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct foo;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { };

template <std::size_t N>
void bar (foo<N> const &)
 { }

int main()
 {
   bar(foo<42u>{});
 }
```

I see that g++ compile where clang++ gives the following error

```
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:32:4: error: no matching function for call to 'bar'
   bar(foo<42u>{});
   ^~~
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:27:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      '__make_integer_seq' against 'integer_sequence'
void bar (foo<N> const &)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

As usual, the question is: who's right? g++ or clang++?

**-- EDIT --** As pointed by HolyBlackCat (thanks!), some older version of clang++ compile this code where the newer don't.

I've tried with Wandbox and I see that clang++ compile from 3.4 (the first version supporting `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence`) to 3.8.1. Starting from 3.9.1 gives the preceding error.

**-- EDIT 2 --** Observe that the clang++ compilation error seems strictly bounded to the use of the first template argument in definition of the default value for the second.

In fact, changing

```
template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct foo;
```

in

```
// ........................... now doesn't depends from N -->VVV
template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<10u>>
struct foo;
```

both compilers compile.

Comment: can't reproduce errors with clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f579c46cd768466

Comment: @ÖöTiib That's some old clang. It seems that it stopped working since Clang 7.

Comment: Works in recent GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/kXj4I-

Comment: Then it is likely quality of implementation issue. You should specify versions in question so we can see if there are already open tickets about the issue.

Comment: @wilx - works starting from g++ 4.9.0, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @ÖöTiib - question edited: according Wandbox, clang++ compile till 3.8.1; gives error from 3.9.1

Comment: Hmm ... Clang has to be wrong ...

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::make_integer_sequence<int, 1>, std::integer_sequence<int, 0>>);` does pass. But it looks like `__make_integer_sequence` is some sort of compiler builtin, which can be used by both [libstdc++](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/utility.html#296) and [llvm's libc++](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/utility.html#296). It seems it normally substitutes the correct type, but when there are dependent template arguments, the substitution doesn't happen early enough for template argument deduction.

Comment: Barry filed a bug for this at llvm: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42757 (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206006 , asked just 4 days apart!)

Answer (score 1):

This is plainly some sort of Clang/libc++ bug: the type `std::make_index_sequence<…>` isn’t `__make_integer_seq`, it’s… `std::index_sequence<…>`.  Type aliases (and alias templates) are transparent, and deduction has always worked for `std::vector` despite its default (allocator) template argument.