# Compiler discrepencies in deduction of template parameter of nested alias template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following code snippet where we we're trying to deduce the template parameter to the function `foobar()`:

```cpp
struct Bar { static constexpr auto size = 5; };

template <class T, class=std::make_index_sequence<T::size>>
struct FooList;
template <class T, std::size_t... Idxs>
struct FooList<T, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Idxs...>> { };

struct Wrapper {
  template <class T>
  using list_type = FooList<T>;
};

template <class T>
void foobar(typename Wrapper::template list_type<T>) { }

void test() { 
  foobar(FooList<Bar>{});
}
```

The major compiler frontends disagree on whether this should compile (see this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E8H0bT)).  If we give the template parameter explicitly, like this:

```cpp
void test_explicit() { 
  foobar<Bar>(FooList<Bar>{});
}
```

all of the major frontends compile the code successfully ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/JDu7nV)).  Interestingly, if we make the deduction simpler:

```cpp
struct Bar { };

struct Wrapper {
  template <class T>
  using my_type = T;
};

template <class T>
void foobar(typename Wrapper::template my_type<T>) { }

void test() { 
  foobar(Bar{});
}
```

a *different* subset of the frontends compile and fail to compile (MSVC being the only one that compiles both, see this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TyoVFW)).

Which implementation is conforming here, and which are buggy (and why)?  Can anyone find the portion of the C++ standard that specifies how this should work?

Comment: I've added the language-lawyer tag as it looks like you want supporting documentation.  fell free to remove it if you fell that is to restrictive.

Comment: I don't think compilers should accept your code at all. You use desambiguator keywords `typename` and `template` on a non dependent expression. In fact, your second example compiles if you remove them.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I suspect permitting extra disambiguators was added to the standard about when they also reduced the places you needed disambiguators, to make removing disambiguators being required not break builds.  But I don't have chapter and verse, nor am I certain.

Comment: As for the question, I recall there being an issue with template aliases that perfectly match or not, and if `template<class T> using trivial=T` would ever match `template<template<class>class X, class T> void test( X<T> ) {}` vs `template<class T> void test2(trivial<T>) {}` and should it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It was my understanding that compilers mostly treat disambiguators as noise in parameters; I vaguely remember something about a change in 14 or 17 that allowed this for consistency. This also doesn't explain why the explicit template argument version works.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm sure it has something to do with perfect matches (especially given the error message from clang in the first example), but I'm not clear about (1) when that applies and (2) whether this is supposed to be a perfect match.

Comment: In case someone else comes across this, here's a [workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/aNnPl3), at least for my use case.

Comment: Filed [llvm 42757](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42757) for the first example and [gcc 91262](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91262) for the second example.

Comment: @Barry: Can you help me understand how `Wrapper::type<T>` not a dependent name?

Comment: @AndyG: Of course it’s dependent, but since `Wrapper` is not dependent, `Wrapper::type` isn’t, and so it’s known to be a type for any `T`.  That’s all that’s needed at the `typename`/`template` level.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133186/g-and-clang-different-behaviour-when-stdmake-index-sequence-and-stdin is another case of the first issue (std::make_index_sequence)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, this is [a clang bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/42102) in the implementation of `__make_integer_seq`. I wanted to offer a workaround:

```cpp
#include <utility>

namespace workaround {
#ifdef __clang__
  template<class T, T N>
  struct make_index_sequence_helper {
      using type = __make_integer_seq<std::integer_sequence, T, N>;
  };

  template<class T, T N>
  using make_integer_sequence = typename make_index_sequence_helper<T, N>::type;

  template<std::size_t N>
  using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>;
#else
  using std::make_integer_sequence;
  using std::make_index_sequence;
#endif
}
```

Then using it in `FooList` works again:

```
template <class T, class=workaround::make_index_sequence<T::size>>
struct FooList;
template <class T, std::size_t... Idxs>
struct FooList<T, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Idxs...>> { };
```